# How to make this site responsive?

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design, responsive

I'm learning HTML and CSS, and now i'm willing to learn how to make it responsive. I've already tried, and in chrome, where you can test in multiple devices, is works, but when i expand / model the browser, it gets strange.

```css
    .back {
        background-color: turquoise
    }

    .center {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        max-height: 25vw;
        max-width: 100vw;
        object-fit: cover;
        padding-top: 1em;
    }

    .perfil {
        position: relative;
        height: auto;
        margin: -8.5em 0em 0.5em 1.25em;
        float: left;
    }

    .text {
        float: right;
        padding-top: 6em;
        padding-left: 1em;
    }

    .nd {
        text-align: left;
    }

    .avatar {
      
        height: auto;
    }

    #name {
        float: left;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        padding-top: 0.4em;
        font-size: 3em;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #par {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Cambria;
        color: black;
        font-size: x-large;
        padding-top: 5em;
    }

    #link {
        font-size: x-large;
        padding-left: 28em;
        margin-top: 40em;
        padding-right: 5em;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

```html
<head> 
    <title> Profile </title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class = "back">

        <div>
            <img src = "images/d8cztm9-a4047ab4-db23-4e70-9c6f-757d5d2b0d36.png"  alt = "Lelouchao" class="center" >
        </div>

        <div class = "perfil"> 
            <img src = "images/119191.png" alt = "avatar" class = "avatar"> 

            
            <div class = "text">
                <p id ="name"> Lelouch Vi Britania </p>
        
            </div>
            
        </div> 
        <a href="https://code-geass.fandom.com/pt-br/wiki/Lelouch_vi_Britannia" target="_blank" id = "link" >Link Interesses</a> 
    <div>

        <p id="par"> Lelouch Lamperouge (ルルーシュ・ランペルージ, Rurūshu Ranperūji?)
            é o protagonista e anti-herói da série de anime da Sunrise, <span style = "text-decoration: overline;" >Code Geass: Lelouch of the Rebellion. </span> Seu sobrenome é um pseudônimo; seu nome real é <span style = "font-weight: bold">Lelouch vi Britannia</span> (ルルーシュ・ヴィ・ブリタニア, Rurūshu vi Buritania?),
            11° príncipe do Santo Império Britanniano e filho do 98° imperador da Britannia, Charles zi Britannia. Lelouch é o líder da Ordem dos Cavaleiros Negros, onde ele expõe sua identidade como <strike>Zero </strike>
            e tem como objetivos vingar-se de seu pai pela misteriosa morte de sua mãe, do seu exílio no Japão e recriar um mundo melhor para sua irmã Nunnally. Seu seiyū japonês é Jun Fukuyama, e sua versão criança é dublada por Sayaka Ohara. 
            Lelouch foi projetado pelo grupo de artistas da CLAMP que ajudaram a criar um personagem atraente devido ao seu estilo e apelo visual. <span class = "nd"><br><br>Ele tem sido reconhecido como um dos personagens mais populares do Japão e desde a sua estreia em Code Geass tem aparecido no topo de diversas pesquisas. As publicações de anime e mangá viram Lelouch como um personagem interessante, embora ele queira destruir um império usando métodos cruéis, ele ainda possui um lado humano que entra em conflito com seus ideais o que o faz um personagem simpático. Jun Fukuyama tem sido elogiado e reconhecido por seu trabalho na interpretação de Lelouch. </span> 
            Jun Fukuyama tem sido elogiado e reconhecido por seu trabalho na interpretação de Lelouch.
        </p>
    </div>

</body>
```

The avatar image is 250x250 pixels and the banner one is 900x300 pixels.

Thank you very much for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

you must use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for controlling the screen size behavior  and I recommend you to use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)